# Possible to use drush to list overrides for all features?

Tags: drush, features

I believe that drush features-diff will list the overrides for a specific feature and that drush features-list will list all features. Is it possible to list all of the overrides for all features, perhaps by piping the results of drush fl to drush fd?

If so, how would one pick up the second field from drush fl to pipe to drush fd? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Running drush fd with no argument will return a list of overridden features-- I take it that this is not what you want, and that instead you want a list of all the actual changes to the code?

Comment: `drush fda -y` is the best answer for this one now, no question in my mind

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current version of Drush, you can show a list of all features and their override state with (both short and long versions of commands shown, with and without the "-y" flag to skip confirmation questions):

```
$ drush features-list
$ drush fl
```

If you want to show only the overridden features:

```
$ drush features-list | grep -E "Overridden|Needs"
$ drush fl | grep -E "Overridden|Needs"
```

To show everything that has been overridden for all features:

```
$ drush features-diff-all
$ drush fda -y
```

To update all features to their currently overridden state:

```
$ drush features-update-all
$ drush fua -y
```

To revert all features to their default state:

```
$ drush features-revert-all
$ drush fra -y
```

Comment: can't edit cause it is less than 6 characters but `drush fl | grep grep -E` should be `drush fl | grep -E`

Comment: Thanks @powpow12.  I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 2):

Just to share or whatever -- I use it all the time, and I would've loved to come across this tip when I was a noob , so...

I run:

```
drush fl | grep -E "Overridden|Needs"
```

...And, I added an alias to my `drushrc.php` to make it even quicker to call upon:

```
$options['shell-aliases']['flovr'] = '!drush fl | grep -E "Overridden|Needs"';
```

That's all, hope it helps someone!  (Also, "first time / long time," so if I've done wrong here, please be gentle :) )

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are missing is `xargs` (available on Mac and Linux, at least).  Also, the magic numbers in your `cut` command are not reliable; use `sed` instead.  It is hard to tell, but I think that drush is outputting tabs as well as spaces, hence the `[:space:]` character class in the following:

```
$ drush fd | grep -E 'Overridden[[:space:]]+$' \
| sed -E 's/[[:space:]]*Enabled[[:space:]]*Overridden[[:space:]]*//' \
| sed -E 's/.*[[:space:]]//' \
| xargs drush fd
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it's possible by piping the results of `drush fd` or `drush fl` to `grep`, which could be used to extract the feature name, then piping that to `drush fd`, but that is no simple task.

If you're using git, another option is, on a clean working directory, run `drush fua` and then `git diff`. You can then run `git reset --hard HEAD` to get back to where you were. A workaround, but possibly simpler.

Comment: If it is possible with drush, then I should be getting close.

drush fd | cut -c28-51 | tail -n +2

gives a list of features that have been overridden without any of the other fd output columns and without the first row title.

However, I can't find a way to pipe that result to drush fd in a way that would give me the detailed results for all overridden features.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to show the code difference for all enabled features not in their default state, use `fda` command:

```
drush features-diff-all --force
```

> `--force` Bypass the confirmations. This is useful if you want to output all of the diffs to a log file.

---

Other option is to use [Features Diff](https://www.drupal.org/project/features_diff) module for that.

> This is a simple modules used to view the diffs of a single or all features modules.

---

To list all *Overriden* feature modules by parsing the output of feature-list, the syntax can be:

```
drush fl --status=enabled | grep -o "\S\+\s\+Enabled.\+" | grep "Overridden"
```

<sup>To have both *Overridden* and *Needs review*, use: `grep -e "Overridden" -e "Needs review"` instead.</sup>

To get the list of modules, filter by: `cut -d' ' -f1`.

For longer name of modules, increase `COLUMNS` variable as names can be cut off.

So to pipe all features into feature-diff (`fd`), feature-revert (`fr`), feature-update (`fu`) or [features cleanup](https://github.com/drupal-modules/features_cleanup) (`fcf`), e.g.

```
COLUMNS=100 drush fl --status=enabled | grep -o "\S\+\s\+Enabled.\+" | grep -e "Overridden" -e "Needs review" | tee | cut -d' ' -f1 | xargs -t drush fcf
```

<sup>For running it in parallel (to speed it up), add `-P4 -L4` into `xargs`.</sup>

Comment: Should `drush features-diff-all --force` be `drush features-diff-all -y`?

Comment: You may try `-y`, however there is a special `--force` option for it (see: `drush help features-diff-all`). I think the difference is that `--force` is suppressing the annoying confirmation message, where `-y` is still displaying it. So `--force` is useful when you're logging the differences to the log file.